# Creating an interface for any amount of attributes with Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following hash table:

```
{
   1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   2: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   ...
}
```

Object key is the number of class and array has the number of students.

How can I define an interface for keys?

```
// pseudo code
interface ClassStudentRelationshipInterface {
   {any amount of keys should be a number}: number[];
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) for the interface with key of type `number`:

```
interface ClassStudentRelationshipInterface {
   [key: number]: number[];
}
```